# Why my Google search results are all directed via "http://www.ecosia.org/"?

Tags: security, browser

Recently I noticed a website called "ecosia.org" which directs all my Google search results. What's happening to me?

Comment: Did you install any extensions? What browser are you using? I went to ecosia.org and it seems to be its own search engine.

Comment: Noticed the same thing today. And yup, I have Window Resizer plugin. Shady.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I didn't have any of these extensions installed but I just noticed an update to the Window Resizer Plugin started redirecting all my Google Search results links through EcoSia to support tree planting in Brazil.  So if you have the Window Resizer plugin or any other plugin that supports Ecosia in a recent update.  That may be the culprit.

Its not spam or a virus though, its a legitimate effort to plant trees in Brazil.  Go to ecosia.org and they're very transparent about it all.

**TO DISABLE ECOLINKS IN WINDOW RESIZER.**

1. Window Resizer settings are at the bottom of the Window Resizer Menu (under all the windows sizes), so click the Window resizer button in your Chrome toolbar.
2. Settings page appears...in that menu there's a big link on the right side called ECOLINKS.  Click that.
3. Only one option there to turn it off...Uncheck that and ur done.

Comment: EXACTLY! I am using Window Resizer. I really don't think this is a good stuff to turn on it be DEFAULT! Thanks!

Comment: Ugh - so shady. I need to stop using extensions. Thanks for the answer!!

Comment: Thanks! I hate it when extensions do not bother to notify you about such updates

Answer (score 6):

You have installed an extension in your browser which causes all of your traffic to be rerouted through the ecosia.org.

I did a simple Google search and found that it is an organisation that donates about 80% of its earning to plant trees.

That being said, if you are worried about your privacy (which, you should be), uninstall the extension or try to change the default search engine.

It can be done as follows (For Chrome):

1. Goto Tools->Settings.
2. Click the Search. Manage Search Engines.
3. If you hover over google, you will get a make default button. Click it. Click OK.

You are done.

Comment: I don't think it works by changing your search engine, but by injecting something dirty into your SERP. That is very dirty play. I doubt with such behaviors they'd donate 80% revenue to the charity.

Answer (score 2):

This is apparently something new with the most up to date version of chrome, as you are not alone.

If you look in your chrome extensions, you will have one called "EcoLinks" which is now enabled by default. You can just turn it off, or uninstall it. Either is up to you.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like Google has removed the extension now. And [here](http://techglimpse.com/google-search-redirect-ecosia-plant-tree-window-resizer/) are some good alternatives to try